# filter_var always gives Email is NOT Valid

Tags: php

I changed `<input type="text" name="url">` to`<input type="email" name="email">` and now it only shows EMAIL is not Valid no matter what I put, why is that?

If I change it to => input type="text" name="url it works. However, if I change it to type = email it only works one way and shows Email is not Valid only

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title> PHP Basics </title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="filters.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Now">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        echo "<h2>Email is Valid</h2>";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Email is NOT Valid</h2>";
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to display whether the email is valid or not. No error messages popped up.

Comment: The problem is on **FILTER_VALIDATE_URL**. You need to validate an **email** not an **URL** so use **FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on **FILTER_VALIDATE_URL**

You need to validate an **email** not an **URL** so use **FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL**

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> PHP Basics </title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="filter.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Now">
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo "<h2>Email is Valid</h2>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<h2>Email is NOT Valid</h2>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's more of a typo. Just put that in the comments. You didn't have to copy the whole code